# Java WAR Tomcat works on XP but not Windows 7

Tags: java, tomcat

Need a bit of help with a Java app we had developed for us. It's running on Tomcat as a WAR and works on Windows XP. It runs on Windows 7 without errors but doesn't actually work. The app communicates with an attached modem to make calls. On Windows 7, it outputs that the call is successful but no call is actually made. Any ideas how I can see where it's missing something?

Comment: Test Driven Development - make a small technical unit test to try out the communication. Only after _if_ that works, start thinking on security managers and so on. Also try the war on an other Windows XP to exclude hard values in code or data.

Comment: The developer built it on an XP box and we tested on site with the modem to make sure everything was working. Then we copied the data over to Windows 7 64bit and it didn't work (gave errors). We reinstalled Windows 7 as 32bit and this time no errors but tests were not successful. I may have to try another Windows XP box to rule out any hard values.

Comment: Need some logs. Maybe, you simply have a loadLibrary problem,  because of different bit 32/64.

Comment: What kind of logs? I'm using XAMMP with Tomcat.